# ¿Porque no puedo acceder al las paginas de laravel en un servidor apache?

Tags: laravel-5, centos, apache2

Acabo de subir un proyecto de laravel a un servidor apache instale los paquetes, instale laravel y todo lo que tiene que ver , entonces cuando ingreso a mi sitio me muestra el login , pero cuando ingreso los datos y para acceder, ingresa pero dice

> Not Found 
>   The request URL/pagina1 was not found on this server
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------
>   Apache/2.2.15(CentOS) Server at.....

Me gustaria saber que estoy haciendo mal. Que no entiendo que me falta configurar.

aquí esta el error
les dejo una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo de arriba esta solucionado , pero lo de abajo de `file does not exist`. es con lo que tengo problema, ya la primera pagina si abre para loguearse.

Comment: ¿Existe la ruta? déjanos ver el archivo de rutas respectivo, o el listado de rutas de artisan.

Comment: asi es , existen las rutas , primero hice la prueba en un servidor virtual con el login y su funcionamiento.antes de subirlo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código donde te da el error.

Comment: Solucionado. el error estaba en cambiar el `AllowOwerride` a `All` , en el archivo `httpd.conf`, ya que estaba en `none `, asi que ahora funciona. Gracias por la ayuda igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisa los log de apache con el siguiente comando que te permitira ver las ultimas lineas del archivo. una vez tienes el erros es mas facil preguntar que se podria hacer.

## tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: lo veré, respondo apenas pueda.

Comment: no encuentra el archivo en public/_debugbar ,la carpeta es httpd no apache 2, mi error!